# configure a PAM module to be required for all but certain users for which it should be sufficient

Tags: linux, pam

I'd like to be able to configure /etc/pam.d/sshd so that:

for all users except those in group "admin", module pam_radius is **required**.

for those users in group admin, module pam_radius is **sufficient**.

How to do this?

Comment: The linked Q&A should cover it. You'd want to change the check `pam_access` is performing from a host based to group based.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link provided by Andrew B (thanks Andrew), I solved this with the following:

in /etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore] pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/ssh.conf
auth    required        pam_radius_auth.so
auth    sufficient      pam_radius_auth.so
@include common-auth
```

I created file /etc/security/ssh.conf:

```
-:ALL EXCEPT admin:ALL
```

This file denies access to all except those in the admin group. The reason I didn't put this line in /etc/security/access.conf is because it would have unintended consequences for other modules using pam_access.so. So it gets its own file.

In a nutshell, this allows admins to be able to login via @common-auth mechanisms (unix, ldap) if radius is down.